# Format of Posted DateTime Value

Tags: c#, json, rest, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to post datetime value in a DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss format. here is the value that I'm posting;

```
{
    "EndDate" : "12.10.2015",
    "StartDate" : "10.11.2015"
}
```

Here is my class:

```
public class Report
{
   public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

public string Post([FromBody]Report value)
{

}
```

When I post it, it is posted as the following format: MM-DD-YYYY

How can I handle it?

Note that I'm coding WepApi App and POST method by Restful API

Posted value is JSON format
Platform is .NET.
C# Language is used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your code?...  Just a snippet where the date is assigned, and where it is read?

Comment: You say you want `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss` but in the example you're posting with periods (irrespective of day/month order). You should post using the ISO 8601 standard.

Comment: How can do that in setter, getter class ? @Lloyd

Comment: @NewPHPer you can convert it when you're posting, using `StartDate.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. It's better than storing a string in the Report class.

Comment: @NewPHPer I've written down my comment as an answer. If it works, please mark as an answer.

Comment: @NewPHPer just *don't* use this format. JSON dates are expected to use the ISO8601 format. Change the *client* code to use the appropriate format.

Comment: @NewPHPer how did you create the JSON string? JSON.Net would create ISO8601 strings. What you posted though looks like a German format. Did you hand-code the string's creation instead of using JSON.Net?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the values while you are posting:

```
StartDate.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
EndDate.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

More helpful information can be found on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's not a good idea. JSON dates are supposed to use the ISO8601 format. Hard-coding such a conversion will lead to more bugs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you look [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) under **The Sortable ("s") Format Specifier** section, it says that's compliant to ISO 8601. Am I missing anything?

Comment: That the date should *not* be in a different format in the first place. On the client side, Json.NET would serialize dates correctly, which means the OP is hand-coding the serialization

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're right if they are using JSON.NET. But I can't see anywhere that they are using JSON.NET